# solr highlighting tokens with synonym expansion

Tags: solr

I want to highlight expanded synonyms in solr search results. Example: I have a set of tags like cardiologist, dentist etc.
Now for cardiologist, I have mapped "heart specialist" as a synonym.
When I search "heart specialist", I want to get cardiologist as the result(which I am getting), with the highlighted tokens as "cardiologist", "heart specialist". But, I get only "cardiologist" in the highlights.

I am expanding synonyms during indexing

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" 
synonyms="synonyms.txt" 
ignoreCase="true" 
expand="true"   
tokenizer="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
```

I am **not** expanding synonyms during querying

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" 
 synonyms="synonyms.txt" 
 ignoreCase="true" 
 expand="false"/>
```

I have googled for this and mostly I get the results of the "multi-word synonym bug" in solr. Not considering that bug(because it is irrelevant), how to get this functionality working?
I am talking about solr versions > 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is how both the standard highlighters work: they highlight the query term (even if there are more tokens with the same position). You would need to implement your own `Highlighter` or switch to query-time synonym expansion (then you always get a snippet with the "original" term from the document).

Comment: Thanks Artur Nowak. But my issue is that solr highlights only "cardiologist"(which is the original term in the document) and does not highlight the word "heart specialist" which is present in the synonyms list and is also present in the query.